# Change element's style in evaluateOnNewDocument

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, puppeteer

I'm trying to evaluate top parameter change in css for an element on new document. As you can see in my sample code 'top' is changed but element in doesn't move in the browser and when I inspect these elements, they have still top: 0; It works when I append copy of this element but this solution won't satisfy me.

```
page.evaluateOnNewDocument( () => {
     const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
            for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                    el.style.top = '50px';
                    console.log(el.className, window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('top')); // prints 50px;

            };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `};` after your for loop, and you are trying to access an undefined variable `el` inside your for loop that does not exist.

The variable `el` should probably be `elements`, and you should be accessing each through its index.

Your code should look like this:

```
page.evaluateOnNewDocument( () =>
{
    const elements = document.getElementsByTagName( '*' );

    for ( let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ )
    {
        elements[i].style.top = '50px';
        console.log( elements[i].className, window.getComputedStyle( elements[i] ).getPropertyValue( 'top' ) );
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that, that was a mistype. However this doesn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that some of elements on the site were rendered later dynamically so context in page.onNewDocument wasn't ready for that. 
Solution was to move this code to page.evaluate where the DOM is fully loaded.